# How to interrupt download and warn user?

Tags: c#, webclient, httphandler, httpcontext, ashx

I'm writing an `IHttpHandler` to get large files over an ftp server and give them to users. If my handler gets an error (for ex. "The remote server returned an error: (426) Connection closed; transfer aborted."), the client gets uncompleted file but he/she doesn't know this. The client sees "Download completed succesfully" message.

How can I force browser to warn user and say that "The download finished with errors, please try again" / "The download interrupted" / "The download cancelled" or something?

```
public class FTPServ : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.mxf");
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/mxf";

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("ftp://user:pass@IP/file"))
        {
            try
            {
                var buffer = new byte[65536 * 2];
                int bytesReceived;
                while ((bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                    context.Response.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //What to do
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }
}
```

**Update**

A user suggested to add an content-length, but I don't know the content-length and for me it's impossible to know.

Comment: How do you tell the user it succeeds? How does this code get called?

Comment: This is an architectural question that cannot be answered in your context without actually knowing your context. You may rethrow the exception, log the exception, wrap it into an exception that is handled by a higher tier, display a message box.

Comment: As stated above, you can do anything in the catch block. For example writing a message to the response stream.

Comment: Whatever I write to the response stream, it doesn't change the download behavior. Ongoing download finished and browser said it is a successful download. Once the download starts, it is eventually finished. What I try to do that I want to stop download and force browsers to warn user. "The download cancelled" or "The download interupted" message is enough for me.

Comment: You should try using something other than `WebClient` for FTP access. FTP actually has richer command model than 'get' and 'store'.

Answer (score 0):

Set a content-length header so the client knows how much to expect.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to tell that I don't know the size of the content and there is no way for me to know that...

Comment: @ogun If you're retrieving it from an FTP server, you should be able to retrieve the size of a file by using the `SIZE` command. Most current FTP servers support this command.

Comment: I'm using some kind of changed FTP protocol. The size of file information is changed by the frame count of the movie file. When you try to use `SIZE` command, it returns frame count.